# threejs corrugated sheet custom shape

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I am building a house like structure with corrugated sheets like below.Here I have used BoxGeometry to draw the structure and updated vertices to make corrugated sheet wall.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, 1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, 1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, -1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, -1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, 1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, 1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, -1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, -1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );


scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5));

var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 0.1, 500, 1, 1);
geom.vertices.forEach(function(v){
 var x_val = Math.abs(v.x);
 if((x_val % 9) < 0.75 || (x_val % 9) > 8.25){
   var m = parseInt(x_val/9) *9;
    var l = 0.75 - (m - x_val);
    v.z =  0.75 * Math.sin(l* Math.PI/1.5);
  }
  else if(x_val % 3 < 0.25 || (x_val % 3) > 2.75){
    var m = parseInt(x_val/3) * 3;
    var l = 0.25 - (m - x_val);
    v.z =  0.25 * Math.sin(l* Math.PI/0.5);
  }
});
geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();

var corrugated = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "silver"}));
scene.add(corrugated);


render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js">   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to build  front side wall with the corrugated sheet as in the below shape

[image]
I have tried with the below code using shape.and tried to updated vertices as the first example.But not getting the desired corrugated pattern.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, 1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, 1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, -1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( 1, -1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, 1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, 1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, -1, 1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

  var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.2);
  directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight1.position.set( -1, -1, -1);
  scene.add( directionalLight1 );

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5));

var wallShape = new THREE.Shape();

wallShape.moveTo( -50, 0 );
wallShape.bezierCurveTo( -50, 33, -50, -66, -50, 100);
wallShape.bezierCurveTo( -32, 116, -16, 132, 0, 150 );
wallShape.bezierCurveTo( 16, 132, 32, 116, 50, 100 );
wallShape.bezierCurveTo( 50, 66, 50, 33, 50, 0 );
wallShape.lineTo(-50, 0 );

var extrudeSettings = { amount: 0.1, bevelEnabled: false, curveSegments: 500};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( wallShape, extrudeSettings );

geometry.vertices.forEach(function(v){
        var yval = Math.abs(v.y);
        if((yval % 9) < 0.75 || (yval % 9) > 8.25){
          var m = parseInt(yval/9) *9;
          var l = 0.75 - (m - yval);
          v.z =  v.z + 0.75 * Math.sin(l* Math.PI/1.5);
        }
});



geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "silver"}));
 scene.add( mesh );

render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js">   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to make the desired corrugated structure?

Comment: I suggest you create your model in a content creation tool like Blender. In this way it's easier to control the visual results especially if your geometry is static and always identical (so you don't have random parts in it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Mugen87 about making the things in creation tools.
But, if for some reasons you don't want to use loadable stuff, then you do something like that, feeling free to transform the geometry as much as you want (a rough concept here):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 15);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5));

var w = 5,
  h = 5;
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(w, h, 0.125, 50, 1, 1);
geom.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
  if (v.y > 0) {
    v.y += (w / 2) - Math.abs(v.x); // here you can use whatever dependency y from x :)
  }
});
geom.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
  v.z += Math.sin(v.x * Math.PI * 2) * .125;
});
geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();

var corrugated = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "silver"
}));
scene.add(corrugated);


render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```